# Error when building the library with Retrolamda Java 8

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrolambda

I'm trying to load a library on Bintray. When building it gives this error. Here are the logs :

```
    Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.                           
    :clean                                                                               
    :app:clean                
    :lib:clean                
    :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE     
    :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE     
    :app:checkDebugManifest                
    :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE     
    :lib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE     
    :lib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE     
    :lib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE     
    :lib:compileLint                
    :lib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE     
    :lib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE     
    :lib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE     
    :lib:checkReleaseManifest                
    :lib:prepareReleaseDependencies                
    :lib:compileReleaseRenderscript                
    :lib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE      
    :lib:generateReleaseResources                 
    :lib:packageReleaseResources                 
    :lib:compileReleaseAidl                 
    :lib:generateReleaseBuildConfig                 
    :lib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE      
    :lib:mergeReleaseAssets                 
    :lib:processReleaseManifest                 
    :lib:processReleaseResources                 
    :lib:generateReleaseSources                 
    :lib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac                 
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    :lib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE            
    :lib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease                 
    :lib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease                 
    :lib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders                 
    :lib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease                 
    :lib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease                 
    :lib:bundleRelease                 
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library                 
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library                 
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library                 
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library                 
    :app:prepareScriptoLibUnspecifiedLibrary                 
    :app:prepareDebugDependencies                 
    :app:compileDebugAidl                 
    :app:compileDebugRenderscript                 
    :app:generateDebugBuildConfig                 
    :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE      
    :app:mergeDebugAssets                 
    :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE      
    :app:generateDebugResources                 
    :app:mergeDebugResources                 
    :app:processDebugManifest                 
    :app:processDebugResources                 
    :app:generateDebugSources                 
    :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac                 
    An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_101). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for
 duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
    com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for java.lang.invoke.MethodType not found
    :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED          
    :app:compileRetrolambdaDebug                                                                   

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

    * Try:        
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED  

    Total time: 1 mins 4.885 secs
```

Error reason is related to the Retrolambda, although I do not use it in the project. Retrolamda used in a separate module from the example of the use of the library .

Stacktrace:

```
* What went wrong:          
Problem configuring task :lib:bintrayUpload from command line.
> Unknown command-line option '-e'.

* Try:                      
Run gradlew help --task :lib:bintrayUpload to get task usage details. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:             
org.gradle.execution.commandline.TaskConfigurationException: Problem configuring task :lib:bintrayUpload from command line.
        at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskConfigurer.configureTasksNow(CommandLineTaskConfigurer.java:64)
        at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskConfigurer.configureTasks(CommandLineTaskConfigurer.java:44)
        at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskParser.parseTasks(CommandLineTaskParser.java:44)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:44)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:143)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:140)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: org.gradle.cli.CommandLineArgumentException: Unknown command-line option '-e'.
        at org.gradle.cli.CommandLineParser$BeforeFirstSubCommand.onStartOption(CommandLineParser.java:329)
        at org.gradle.cli.CommandLineParser.parse(CommandLineParser.java:136)
        at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskConfigurer.configureTasksNow(CommandLineTaskConfigurer.java:61)
        ... 52 more
```

Comment: did you check the compiler error output?

Comment: as your print suggests: run with --stacktrace to get the stacktrace

Comment: i added stacktrace in the question

Comment: this is my build command:

gradlew clean build bintrayUpload -PbintrayUser=user -PbintrayKey=key -PdryRun=false -encoding UTF-8 --stacktrace